# ¿Se puede crear variables de forma automatica de la siguiente forma en Python?

Tags: python, class

Creo una clase y quiero asignar diferentes datos, pero necesito que el usuario pueda, en este caso, conseguir(ingresara la cantidad por teclado) de empleados que desee.

```
class Empleado:
pass

##creación de variables de tipo Empleado

e1 = Empleado()
e1.legajo = 1
e1.nombre = 'Juan'
e1.direccion = 'Calle 1'
e1.sueldo = 10000
e1.antiguedad = 10

e2 = Empleado()
e2.legajo = 2
e2.nombre = 'Luis'
e2.direccion = 'Calle 2'
e2.sueldo = 20000
e2.antiguedad = 15

e3 = Empleado()
e3.legajo = 3
e3.nombre = 'Pedro'

##Necesitaria una forma de que se ingrese por teclado un número x y que se creen esa cantidad
```

Comment: Un ciclo for basta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pide el numero de datos por un input y luego haces un ciclo `for` y luego vas pidiendo los valores.

```py
numero_empleados = int(input("ingrese el número de empleados: "))

for i in range(numero_empleados):
    e1 = Empleado()

    nombre = input(f"Ingrese el nombre del empleado #{i}: ")
    direccion = input(f"Ingrese la direccion del empleado #{i}: ")
    sueldo = input(f"Ingrese el sueldo del empleado #{i}: ")
    antiguedad = input(f"Ingrese la antiguedad del empleado #{i}: ")

    e1.legajo = i+1
    e1.nombre = nombre 
    e1.direccion = direccion 
    e1.sueldo = sueldo 
    e1.antiguedad = antiguedad
```

Lo más probable es que quieras acceder a estos objetos creados, por lo que mejor guardaremos la referencia del objeto en una lista, de esta forma podremos acceder a ellos. Por lo que haríamos:

```py
numero_empleados = int(input("ingrese el número de empleados: "))
empleados = []

for i in range(numero_empleados):
    e1 = Empleado()

    nombre = input(f"Ingrese el nombre del empleado #{i}: ")
    direccion = input(f"Ingrese la direccion del empleado #{i}: ")
    sueldo = input(f"Ingrese el sueldo del empleado #{i}: ")
    antiguedad = input(f"Ingrese la antiguedad del empleado #{i}: ")

    e1.legajo = i+1
    e1.nombre = nombre 
    e1.direccion = direccion 
    e1.sueldo = sueldo 
    e1.antiguedad = antiguedad
    empleados.append(e1)
```

Si quieres ver los daros del primer empleado solo haces `print(empleados[0].nombre)`.